# how to check if number begins with "+" in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]I need to check if a number begins with "+" or "00" or "(" but when I try with this formule:

```
=IF(LEFT(E4="+",1),1,0)
```

I get an error `#VALUE`

[image]

Comment: `=IF(LEFT(E4,1)="+"...`

Comment: =IF(LEFT(E4,1)="+",1,0) I do exactly the same and I got 0, despite the fact that number contains "+"

Comment: That means that the first character is not a `+`. Is there a leading space?

Comment: I added screen, the first character is "+"

Comment: In a new cell, put `=LEFT(E4, 1)`. The result will not be `+`. There's something before the `+`.

Comment: you're right, there is a space

Comment: Then perhaps use `TRIM`.

Comment: =OR(IF(LEFT(TRIM(E4),1)="+",1,0),IF(LEFT(TRIM(E4),2)="00",1,0),IF(LEFT(TRIM(E4),5)="(*)",1,0)) but still it doesn't work for number that begins with (***).

Comment: Why do you have `LEFT(TRIM(E4), 5)` for that scenario?... why the `5`?

Comment: okay so I changed for 2 but still I don't get results with ()

Comment: Added screen, there are examples on 1st screen

Answer (score 2):

Try to include `OR` logic including a wildcard in a `COUNTIF` and use that in an `IF`:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(E2,{"+*","(*","00*"})),"This","That")
```

If you got leading spaces in front of the `+` then just add a space before the criteria. I guess you could also add another criteria like `" +*`. Unfortunately `TRIM()` won't work within a `COUNTIF`.

Comment: It doesn't work still when I added space before the criteria

Comment: Did you actually use this formula? Please add a comment with exactly how you used it @ola1996